# ¿Cómo podría completar mi código para hacer un rectángulo?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, condiciones, rectangle

En este ejercicio tengo que hacer un rectángulo utilizando Arrays bidimensionales que recorren de 10 a 15 líneas y de 20 a 30 columnas. En los márgenes del rectángulo tengo que poner "#" mientras que en el relleno tengo que poner, en una de cada tres casillas, "-". De momento tengo este código:

```
public class rectangulo{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int filas = (int)(Math.random() * 15) + 10;
    int columnas = (int)(Math.random() * 30) + 20;
    char [][] tablero = new char[filas][columnas];
  // Relleno del tablero
    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
            if(Math.random()<0.33){
                tablero[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }
    }
    //Margen del tablero
    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
            tablero[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }

  //Resultado 
    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
            System.out.print(tablero[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

No sabría cómo completarlo o qué errores tengo. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Primero de todo decir que las funciones random() están erroneamente definidas. `Math.random()` devuelve un valor entre 0.0 y 1.0. Si quieres que el valor esté comprendido entre dos valores la fórmula genérica es: (Math.random() * (max-min)) + min.

De este modo el código queda así:

```
int filas = (int)(Math.random() * 5) + 10; //15-10=5
int columnas = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 20; //30-20=10
```

Por otro lado, para rellenar los márgenes en el bucle for basta con incluir una condición que cumplan todas las casillas de los márgenes. Se me ocurre por ejemplo que una casilla está en el margen siempre y cuando su fila sea 0 o (filas-1) o su columna sea 0 o (columnas-1).

El resto de casillas por tanto son casillas intermedias por lo que podemos usar la condición opuesta. Para rellenar una de cada tres con un "-" podemos recorrerlas y un con un contador reseteable cada tres iteraciones (ponerlo a 0 o usar el operador %3 para múltiplos de 3) manejamos esta condición.

El código sería algo así:

```
public class rectangulo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int filas = (int)(Math.random() * 5) + 10;
        int columnas = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 20;
        char [][] tablero = new char[filas][columnas];
        int counter=0;
        // Relleno del tablero
        for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
                if (i!=0 && i!=filas-1 && j!=0 && j!=columnas-1) {
                    if(counter%3==0){ 
                         tablero[i][j] = '-';
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        //Margen del tablero
        for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
                if (i==0 || i==filas-1 || j==0 || j==columnas-1) {
                    tablero[i][j] = '#';
                }
            }
        }

        //Resultado 
        for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columnas; j++){
                System.out.print(tablero[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda !

Comment: Un apunte, como bien dice @MrSman `Math.random()` devuelve entre 0.0 y 1.0 pero OJO sin incluir este último

Comment: Cierto es @JDev.. cosa que puedes solucionar con la fórmula genérica `(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min` si no me confundo.Siempre y cuando se quiera incluir en este caso el valor 15 para las filas y el valor 30 para las columnas.

Comment: se te ha olvidado poner el `else` en el primer `for` para que imprima espacios, y ponerle el contador también dentro de ese `else`